How to solved foreground service problem for on download listener webview?
I am using Foreground service it's working fine all components when I close app or killed app the foreground also working background. But the problem is when I used the same foreground inside webview.onDownloadLisener() then it's working when app is opened. After closing or killed the foreground terminate problem.
Note same foreground when I used Mainactivity or any adaptor class it's working fine.
May I miss any this for using this inside webview ondownloadlisener?
Or need any settings enable for using foreground for webview?
